# jQuery as one variable increase another decreases

Tags: jquery, html

wondering if there is a way of decreasing one variable based on the increased value of another. I have some elements I would like to manipulate depending on the scroll position of the window. I have got the scroll position

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
        secondVar = 100;

        if(windowScroll++){
            *make secondVar decrease by 1*
        }
    });
});
```

But what i cant figure out is how to have it so if `windowScroll` increases by 1, another variable decreases by 1? Cant even get my head around where to begin!

EDIT

Got my head around it, this is what i was trying to achieve.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

var windowScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
    startPoint = 100,           // where to begin scrolling
    scrollDistance = 400,           // how long the effect lasts in scroll distance 
    fadeTarget = $('img');          // what to fade

    if(windowScroll >= startPoint){
        startScroll = windowScroll - startPoint,
        opacity = 1 - (startScroll / scrollDistance);
        fadeTarget.css("opacity", opacity);
    }
    else{
    fadeTarget.css("opacity", 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you need it, 1 - 1 still equals zero ?

Comment: @adeneo but im not doing 1 - 1, im doing a variable that may be any number, lets say 500, take away 1 and you have 499.

Comment: Increases with 1 from what, windowScroll is set on every scroll, and if you set an initial scrollTop variable on page load, it will be 0, so 100 - scrollTop would be the same thing, so 1-1 does equal zero, so what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: ah right ok yea, i am only executing the script between certain scroll points, at the beginning we have 100 - 0, then i need all the values between 100 - 0 and 100 - 100, then nothing after that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `secondVar` based on value of `windowScroll`:

```
var secondVar = 100 - windowScroll
```

Of course there could be any other number, 100 is just an example.
Note that now the bigger `windowScroll` is, the smaller `secondVar` will get.

Comment: He wants to decrease it by 1 not by windowScroll value.

Comment: Nope. He wants to decrease it by 1 if `windowScroll` increases by 1, which is exactly how my code behaves.

Comment: @MichałRybak is correct, if secondVar is 100 and onload the windowScroll is 0, then as windowScroll increases to 1, secondVar becomes 99 and so on.